# Unable to push files to git due to: failed to push some refs

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a directory that i want to turn into a git project.

I created a new project in gitlab and then i did the following:

```
git init
git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:a/b/c.git
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push -u origin master
```

In addition, I created the following `.gitignore` file:

```
*
!*/scripts
!*/jobs
```

After running `git push -u origin master` i got the following error:

```
Counting objects: 33165, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (32577/32577), done.
Writing objects: 100% (33165/33165), 359.84 MiB | 1.70 MiB/s, done.
Total 33165 (delta 21011), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (21011/21011), done.
remote: GitLab: 
remote: A default branch (e.g. master) does not yet exist for a/b/c
remote: Ask a project Owner or Maintainer to create a default branch:
remote: 
remote:   https://gitlab.com/a/b/c/project_members
remote: 
To gitlab.com:a/b/c.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab.com:a/b/c.git'
```

What could be the issue?
Please advise

Comment: Well, it seems that no default branch exists in that repository. You should talk to your project owner or maintainer to create a default branch.

Comment: I already have a default branch (master). Any other idea?

Comment: Side note: technically, the problem is clear enough: *you* have a `master` branch, but the *GitLab repository* does not! That's why they think you need special permissions: your push is going to *create* the branch on the GitLab side.

Comment: ok so how to create a master on the gitlab side

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This is linked to [issue 27456](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/27456) and [merge request 6608](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/6608):

> document the need to be owner or have the master permission level for the initial push

So it might be a permission level, not a branch issue.

See [commit 81ee443](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/commit/81ee4436dbb91e345149204123c125dab387e524):

> You will need to be owner or have the master permission level for the initial push, as the master branch is automatically protected.

Comment: You can create a new repo in a group yet not have permission to push to it. Gitlab permissions are weird.

Comment: yep, I'm owner of the project and still have the error under gitlab

Comment: @yota Could you ask a separate question with more details( GitLab version, OS, URL used: HTTPS or SSH, ...)

Answer (score 9):

I had this issue for quite some time as well. Tried different things, but it did not work. The owner of the GitLab repository of my company changed my status from "Developer" to "Maintainer" and it finally worked for me.

Comment: This was it for me. Says the same as the other answer, but makes it clearer what needs to be done.

Comment: Glad that it worked for you @questionto42standswithUkraine. :)

Answer (score 4):

There's 2 ways to resolve this:

1. Elevate the developer-in-question's privileges to at least "Maintainer", or
2. Another maintainer can go into the repository's "Settings" -> "Repository", and under "Protected Branches", and create an entry for `main` (or whatever you want the default branch to be), and set it up so the user who created the repo can also push to main. The result will look like this:
   [image: protected branch settings]
   Gitlab will show the `main` branch as "deleted" because it doesn't yet exist, but the developer will now be able to push their code.