# Creating a README.md in GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab, commit, readme

I created a new blank project in GitLab (in the browser). I checked the "Initialize repository with a README" box. But when opening it, it says: "The repository for this project is empty." I assume I still need to initialize a README.md file so that the main branch exists? So in the command line I tried (I am using windows 10):

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/url/myproject.git
cd myproject
git switch -c main
touch README.md
git add README.md
git commit -m "add README"
```

But it says:

```
C:\Users\me>git clone https://gitlab.com/ur/myproject.git
fatal: destination path 'myproject' already exists and is not an empty directory.

C:\Users\me>cd myproject

C:\Users\me\myproject>git switch -c main
fatal: A branch named 'main' already exists.

C:\Users\me\myproject>touch README.md
'touch' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\me\myproject>git add README.md

C:\Users\me\myproject>git commit -m "add README"

On branch main
Your branch is based on 'origin/main', but the upstream is gone.
  (use "git branch --unset-upstream" to fixup)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

My project is still empty and I can't add or push anything. Why?

EDIT: If I navigate to the project and do `dir`, I get (I only deleted the volume serial number):

```
C:\Users\me\myproject>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is ...

 Directory of C:\Users\me\myproject

13.12.2021  09:29    <DIR>          .
13.12.2021  09:29    <DIR>          ..
13.12.2021  09:29                 0 README.md
               1 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  112.515.997.696 bytes free
```

Comment: This is likely to devolve into lots of comments. First `touch` is a *nix command so doesn't exist on windows. Making a README.md file in your editor and saving it will work. Try removing your `myproject` directory, and cloning again and doing `dir` to see what files you have.

Comment: @doctorlove I navigated to the project and posted in the original post what I got. I can't create a README.md from the browser because I don't have that button. But if I go to my computer in the folder, there is a README.md file...

Comment: @doctorlove If I delete the folder from my computer and clone it again, it says I have cloned an empty repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break the errors down one by one.

```
C:\Users\me>git clone https://gitlab.com/ur/myproject.git
fatal: destination path 'myproject' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

The `myproject` folder already exists - most likely you've already cloned the project, so nothing more to do here.

```
C:\Users\me\myproject>git switch -c main
fatal: A branch named 'main' already exists.
```

You can't create a `main` branch since it already exists - so again, nothing to do here.

```
C:\Users\me\myproject>touch README.md
'touch' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

`touch` is a *nix command that doesn't exist in Windows. One option is to use Git Bash instead of CMD, which provides a `touch` executable. Alternatively, you could use [another method to create an empty file in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1702762/2422776).

```
C:\Users\me\myproject>git add README.md

C:\Users\me\myproject>git commit -m "add README"

On branch main
Your branch is based on 'origin/main', but the upstream is gone.
  (use "git branch --unset-upstream" to fixup)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

These two commands didn't fail, they just did nothing because the `README.md` file wasn't created. Once you create it you can repeat these two commands and they should succeed.

Comment: I now deleted the directory in my computer, cloned it again, navigated to it, switched to a new branch "main", but now the last two commands failed, like you said. Silly question, but how do I create the `README.md` file? There is no option in the web interface and I thought I could do it with git add.

Comment: OK, I used bash and added it, it is in my folder on my computer. But it's still not on the web browser.

Comment: `git add` just stages a file to be committed, it doesn't create it - you'll have to do that in some native way of your OS (see, e.g., the link I shared).  WRT "there is no option in the web interface" - I think I lost you here. What web interface are you referring to?

Comment: What I wanted to say is that, despite following the commands and commiting (I did everything in bash), and the README.md file appearing in the folder in my system, if I go to the web page of the project, it still says "The repository for this project is empty".

Comment: @futuredataengineer Thanks for clraifying. There's a missing step here. These instructions end with creating a commit in your local repository. If you want this change to appear in the remote repository, you need to push it (`git push origin main`).

Comment: It says the following: `remote: A default branch (e.g. main) does not yet exist for myname/myproject
remote: Ask a project Owner or Maintainer to create a default branch:
remote:
remote:   https://gitlab.com/myname/myproject/-/project_members
remote:
To https://gitlab.com/myname/myproject.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.com/myname/myproject.git'`

Comment: @futuredataengineer sounds like a permission issue - see https://stackoverflow.com/q/52026119/2422776

Answer (score 1):

1. Repo-session
   mandatory
   Score: 0.00% (Checks completed: 0.00%)
   Create a new directory called 0x03-git in your alx-zero_day repo.

Make sure you include a not empty README.md in your directory:

at the root of your repository alx-zero_day
AND in the directory 0x03-git
And important part: Make sure your commit and push your code to Github - otherwise the Checker will always fail.

Repo:

GitHub repository: alx-zero_day